# How to switch 12V water pump

Tags: motor, relay

I found this pump:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-Ultra-quiet-DC-12V-3M-240L-H-Brushless-Submersible-Water-Pump-High-Qualtiy-mini/32472119699.html

Now, I want to control it from an Arduino.

Is this a good relay to use?

https://www.pololu.com/product/2480?

I want to use a 12v battery for the pump.

Comment: You don't need a relay - a simple N-channel MOSFET will do the job. Oh, and don't forget the flyback diode. A pump is just a motor, after all.

Comment: You need to check the voltage rating and the current rating of the relay. So in your case, the relay should have a rating of at least 12V DC, and 0.35A of current. Both values are really low, so almost any relay will work. The relay you linked to doesn't have a DC rating, only an AC. But I don't think that's a problem in this case.

Comment: @Gerben A general rule of thumb: DC rating is 1/10th - 1/20th of the AC rating. Current remains constant. It's all about arc extinguishing - AC auto-extinguishes at the zero crossing, DC doesn't.

Comment: @Majenko thank you. I didn't know about that rule of thumb. I knew it was lower. Since the pump in question is only 350mA,  the 10/5A relay from pololu should work.

Answer (score 1):

I see people are recommending mosfets (which is the best option). Keep reading this if you still want to use relay. There are two kind of relays, mechanical and solid state. Mechanicals are cheap but they can be noisy (they make sound) also they have low life expectancy compared to solid state relays. On the other hand solid state relays are faster with everything else but they are expensive. Also you need to check voltage and max current rates before buying.

Comment: Some solid state relays only work on AC, so they won't work in this application.

Comment: @Gerben . . There are solid state relays for DC :  http://www.crydom.com/en/products/catalog/e_l_dc.pdf

Answer (score 1):

About the relay, you can buy a low cost relay from aliexpress like the following one or other variant.

https://m.aliexpress.com/item/32392799916.html#autostay

It's well within your desired voltage and current  range and works readily with arduino.